# The USB connected notification is not showing. How do I change connection mode?

Tags: usb-connection-mode

Normally, you can change USB connection mode by clicking the notification. I once changed that mode from the default, and since then I cannot see the notification. This means I also cannot switch back to default mode of operation.

What can I do?

Comment: I have seen several devices that have an entry in the Development menu for selecting the default USB mode. by default is is charging only but using this setting I could change it e.g. to "MTP / file transfer". Don't know if this is vendor specific.